# Why does Better Call Saul show future events in black and white?

Tags: cinematography, better-call-saul

Throughout *Better Call Saul* Season 6, all future events (after the main storyline of *Breaking Bad* ends and Saul lives a low-profile life in exile) are shown in black and white.

Normally, events happening in the past are shown as black and white, while events in the present or future are shown in full color.

Why does *Better Call Saul* reverse this common practice?

Comment: It gives it a cool old-fashioned film noir feel, similar to the classic movies that Kim and Jimmy would enjoy after a hard day's lawyering/scamming/selling drop-phones.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The color change serves to immediately alert the viewer to the time jump. Generally it is the past that is shown without color, however since moments in the past are predominant in the series doing so would make viewing annoying. The lack of color highlights the fact that Saul's quality of life has declined (in a sense it is as if he is traveling backward from success to failure) and that he has had to suppress his bursting personality, which gives a depressed flavor to the scenes. Maybe when Saul makes his personality re-emerge with his flamboyant clothes and maybe he meets Kim again the colors will reappear, that would be amazing.

As noted by @aleppke in the comments, black and white is also used to maintain stylistic consistency with Breaking Bad, where in the second season this technique had already been used to depict future events.

Comment: Wasn't the opening scene of the show also a black and white flash-forward?

Comment: Breaking Bad also used black and white to depict future events in its teasers during season 2: [Source](https://breakingbad.fandom.com/wiki/Seven_Thirty-Seven_Down_Over_ABQ). There's a reasonable chance that they made the same decision for Better Call Saul to maintain stylistic consistency. The fade to colour occurred in BB when the events of the main story were about to catch up to the flash-forward so it is not unreasonable to expect something similar in the BCS finale.

Comment: I agree with most of this answer, but would you care to elaborate on black and white being “annoying”?

Comment: I think I've first seen this in NCIS, where events happening later in an episode would appearch in a short black and white preview.

Comment: @DaG The use of black and white is useful to set a nostalgic tone (as in Mank) or to emphasize a sudden change in time or emotion (as in Better Call Saul). In my opinion, however, it should only be used if it makes real artistic sense. For example, using it in Better Call Saul to visualize the past would be counterproductive, because it would give a depressed tone to the sparkling part of Saul's life and, since the past is predominant, it would be redundant.

Comment: @DaG Because I, like many other people, am not used to seeing entire films/series in black and white, out of habit it seems strange to me and feels like something is missing from the scene. Finally, for those who have vision problems, the lack of brightness/color makes it more difficult to see. Perhaps this widespread opinion is just due to habit, but it is still something to consider before addressing the public